# why is an uninitialized constexpr variable not constant?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, constexpr

I'm not sure if this is a compiler bug or if I misunderstand constexpr:

```
struct S{};
constexpr S s1{};
constexpr S s2;

struct test{
    static constexpr auto t1 = s1;
    static constexpr auto t2 = s2;  //error here
};
```

GCC 4.8 is giving me an odd error "error: field initializer is not constant". Is s2 really not a constant? If so why?

For clarity I actually am using a bunch of empty structs in my code (for meta programming https://github.com/porkybrain/Kvasir) so I really am interested in this specific example.

Comment: For clang, *default initialization of an object of const type 'const S' requires a user-provided default constructor* [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/858633b06d501e42)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** The code should compile, because `[class.ctor]/5` reads:

> The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no *ctor-initializer* (12.6.2) and an empty *compound-statement*. If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the requirements of a `constexpr` constructor (7.1.5), the implicitly-defined default constructor is `constexpr`.

And since `S` is just an empty struct, the implicitly defined default constructor is empty and thus satisfying `constexpr` requirements.

So here you are dealing with imperfection of the compilers, which you have to workaround somehow.

---

Old answer:

Clang emits more sensible error message:

```
main.cpp:3:13: error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const S' 
requires a user-provided default constructor
constexpr S s2;
            ^
```

[dcl.constexpr]/9 provides the explanation and even almost exactly your code as an example:

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have
>   literal type and shall be initialized.(...)
>   [ *Example:*

```
struct pixel {
    int x, y;
};
constexpr pixel ur = { 1294, 1024 };// OK
constexpr pixel origin; // error: initializer missing
```

> *—end example* ]

Comment: That probably shouldn't be necessary for an empty struct, and I think there was a proposal to change the standard for it. I cannot look it up now (commenting is hard enough on a phone) but if you can find it it may be worth including it in your answer.

Comment: Providing a `constexpr` default constructor enables the definition of `s2` without an initializer, as `clang`'s error message hints. Interestingly, while gcc accepts `constexpr S() = default;`, clang does not (as of 3.6). I believe that clang is in error, since [dcl.constexpr]/4 allows this declaration, [dcl.constexpr]/9 only demands a constant expression, and [expr.const] treats this case like any other `constexpr` constructor, but in practice this means that `constexpr S() { }` is required for portability.

Comment: @Wintermute I'm in doubt now because according to `[class.ctor]/5` the implicit default ctor for `S` should be `constexpr`, so the code should compile as is.

Comment: @AntonSavin Hmm...but then the example in [dcl.constexpr]/9 would make no sense, so it's more probable that I'm overlooking something. I'll take a closer look later.

Comment: @Wintermute no, it makes sense because `struct pixel` contains data members so its implicit default constructor is not `constexpr`

Comment: @AntonSavin Yeah, you're right; I misread things. Then the code is conforming, as far as I can tell. Although...two major compilers claiming that it isn't warrants a closer look. Maybe there's something I'm not seeing (yet).